# Buscar un elemento y luego borrarlo usando una Cola (queue) en C++ con librería estandard (stl)

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Buenas, tengo una pregunta con respecto a un código que estoy desarrollando en c++, usando pilas con la libreria stl. Me piden que  desarrolle en C++ un programa, usando el TAD COLA(Enteros), que permita a un
usuario ingresar números enteros que serán almacenados en la cola. Luego se debe
"purgar" la cola, es decir eliminar las repeticiones de elementos, dejando un solo
elemento de los que estén repetidos.

Lo que llevo es lo siguiente:

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main(){
queue<int>cola;

int size;
cout<<"De que longitud desea que sea la cola?"<<endl;
cin>>size;

int n;
for(int i = 1; i<= size; i++){
cout<<"Ingrese un Dato en la Cola: " << endl;
cin >> n;
cola.push(n);}
cout<<"La longitud de la Cola es: " <<cola.size()<<endl;
cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;


cout<<"Cola: "<<endl;

while(!cola.empty())
{
cout<<cola.front()<< " ";
cola.pop();
cout<<endl;

}
system("pause");
}
```

Sé que tendría que hacer una comparación y así buscar el elemento, pero no sé como. Recuerdo que no puedo implementar estructuras sino solo usando la librería de colas #include"queue" que así es es más sencillo, después de todo. Gracias por sus respuestas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma de resolverlo seria crear una funcion que busque si un elemento esta repetido y otra que recorre la cola y en base a la funcion anterior genere una nueva estructura con los datos ya filtrados.

Implementacion

```
#include <iostream>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;


bool estaRepetido(queue<int> cola,int valor){
    int cont=0;
    while(!cola.empty()){
        if(cola.front()==valor){
            cont++;
            if(cont>0) return true;
        }
        cola.pop();
    }
    return false;
}

queue<int> filtrar(queue<int>cola){
    queue<int> resultado;

    while(!cola.empty()){

        int valor=cola.front();
        cola.pop();
        if(!estaRepetido(cola,valor)){
            resultado.push(valor);
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   queue<int> cola;

   int size;
   cout<<"De que longitud desea que sea la cola?"<<endl;
   cin>>size;

   int n;
   for(int i = 1; i<= size; i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese un Dato en la Cola: " << endl;
        cin >> n;
        cola.push(n);
   }
   cout<<"La longitud de la Cola es: " <<cola.size()<<endl;
   cout<<endl<<endl;

   //elimina datos reptidos
   queue<int> datosFiltrados=filtrar(cola);

   //imprimir datos
   while(!datosFiltrados.empty())
   {
        cout<<datosFiltrados.front()<<" ";
        datosFiltrados.pop();
   }



    return 0;
}
```

Aunque no lo mencionas se puede ir filtrado los datos al momento de que el usuario esta ingresando los datos asi nos evitamos tener que filtrar toda la estructura posteriormente y con lo cual ganamos tiempo y memoria.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta!

Comment: de nada Grecia espero te haya servido.